# How to set up Git with Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: git, github, repository, aptana, aptana3

I'm new to Git. I use Aptana 3 for everything and I really want to use it when working with Git as well. The problem I'm running into is that everything I read seems geared towards people who know Git or have an idea of what is going on. I have neither. I've never even used GitHub before not even to clone a project.

As far as I've gotten with the Aptana setup is going into the preferences and setting the path to my git executable. I've restarted it and everything and it appears to have accepted this new path, however, there is nothing different. From reading some of these forums I'm supposed to have access to git commands now, which I have a "commit" command, but no push or pull.

Is there a step-by-step documentation out there, website tutorial, anything for Git noobs and Aptana 3? I spent the day trying to figure it out and my shop really wants to have it set up and running tomorrow for our current project. They've never used it either so are learning how to set it up on their Linux machines. It's up to me to figure it out for the Mac.

I know my issue stems a bit farther then just getting it set up but for now I'd be satisfied in knowing that I have it proper and can push and pull from the central repository once I get that set up as well.

So tutorial, hand-holding, anything available out there? Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I know this was writen much later then asked for, but for future reference

Try this as a starting place,

1: Go to your account on github and create the repo you want to use. Maybe add a md file.

2: Then in Aptana, File - Import - Git - Git Repository as New Project, follow directions on screen for github username & password and the url for the repo (you can go to your github account and copy the url ('https://github.com/userName/repoName.git')

3: Do some work in Aptana, add files, folder, etc. then in Aptana's project browser right click on the project name, team - stage, commit, push (in that order)

4: Go to github and marvel at your new work

I am doing this from a windows machine, but it should be similar on Mac

Comment: Yeah I almost exclusively use Sublime Text 2 nowadays but thanks for the addition.

Comment: I do think it's funny you're the second person to create an account just to answer this question. I didn't think it was that interesting lol.

Comment: This is by far the best answer and should be the accepted answer. I'm a brand newbie to this integration and to GitHub, but I love Aptana Studio. I followed these directions and it worked for the very first time. Awesome answer here!

Comment: What if you are working from BitBucket and not github itself?

Comment: can aptana handle git without the use of a remote - i want to use git without a remote on my local machine - any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: How would I do the same thing with files/projects from a live server? Because I don't seem to have the same options when I right click on a directory on a live server.

Answer (score 2):

I also run Aptana 3 on an iMac. There's a couple of tutorials out there to get GIT running, but what I found easiest by far is to install GitHub for Mac. That takes care of all the installing and required libraries, and the next time you run Aptana, it will automatically recognize the executable.

You can download that app over here: http://mac.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

I worked using Aptana with git for some time, you can commit the changes and compare the files using aptana but for push,pull or other operations, use terminal to execute the commands.

Aptana doesn't gives options for push and pull operations.

Comment: I use push and pull all the time from Aptana.

Answer (score 1):

1- You can find this useful www.screenr.com/2d7s
 -if you find an error saying "Untracked working tree file ......"
 then you go to aptana's console an move into the correct folder
 (where you wanna save the files)- if not just jump to step 2.

2.-Then you just clone the repo you want, follow 
help.github.com/fork-a-repo/

Works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

**git options stopped to show up in Aptana 3**, and you only see the option "Apply patch", the solution is:

**Restart the application.**

Observation: I use Aptana 3 in Ubuntu 14.04.