# Git Commands in Toolbar

Tags: git, aptana

Is there a way to get the Standard Git Buttons (Stage,Unstage,Status,Commit, etc, ) in the standalone version of Aptana 3  in the Toolbar?

Because if I go to  "Customize Perspective... --> Tool Bar Visibility --> Team"

1. The Team is greyed out
2. In the Goup Team is just one Icon an that's not one of the Git icons

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up Git with Aptana Studio 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677837/how-to-set-up-git-with-aptana-studio-3)

Comment: Not really. I can use Git. But i would like to have the Buttons at the Toolbar and not in the "Menu Visibility"

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the tab 'Command group availability' (in 'Customise perspective' window) and check 'Git' there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the GIT GUI elements can be found in the project explorer.