# How to export a project created on Aptana Studio on Github?

Tags: github, aptana, aptana3

I have created a Rails project on Aptana Studio 3 and now I want to put it in a repository on Github. I red [How to set up Git with Aptana Studio 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677837/how-to-set-up-git-with-aptana-studio-3) but the solution given in it is the other way. So, my question is how to export my project (for first time) in my empty Github repository ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: You did select the right answer initially! Your question was about Aptana. The answer is not about what your question was!

Comment: I managed to find the solution thanks to @Bentaye answer, that's why I awarded him the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply follow github's tutorial here https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/
It work for any project

Comment: When I do this, I get a fatal error as you can see in the edit. How can I fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Can you check your version of git `git --version`?

Comment: 1.9.4.msysgit.2. Thanks

Comment: @MysteryGuy I have updated my answer accordingly. Note: your question was about Aptana, not the command-line. But I have updated the answer for both.

Comment: The latest version is 2.16.2, I suggest you update your git and try again.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try it

Comment: How can I change my Git version ? I downloaded 2.16.2 version but Git Bash still uses the old one. Thanks

Comment: @Bentaye I've got this error : `$ git push origin master
To https://github.com/polytech1/PTI.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/polytech1/PTI.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: I am not good enough with git to sort this out, the same issue is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357108/git-updates-were-rejected-because-the-remote-contains-work-that-you-do-not-have

Comment: @Bentaye finally it went, i recreated a project from scratch. :) Thanks

Comment: @MysteryGuy I'm glad we sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

Since [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3.html) is based on Eclipse, and includes [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), you can follow the [EGit GitHub tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial) to push your local repo to your new empty GitHub repo.

As long as you

- [create a local Git repo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Getting_Started) and did one local commit,
- configure your remote repo credentials ([for instance your GitHub SSH key](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration))

you will be able to specify "Add all branches spec" to your push configuration.

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/7/75/Egit-0.10-github-push-refspec.png]

If you are using HTTPS (or even SSH) you need a recent [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.16.1).
Not the 1.9.4 you show.
That is because because [GitHub just disabled TLSV1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48953156/6309) a few days ago.