# Getting fatal error at the time of - git pull - SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD

Tags: git, pull-request

I am getting error at the time of - git pull , Error is “ Fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repository.git/': error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number?” . Please suggest solution.

Comment: What is your git version and your OS?

Comment: Git version is -  2.14.1.windows.1 and OS is windows 7

Comment: Is this a path issue? Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309, with a simplified path and Git 2.16.2 (no setup required: simply uncompress https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.16.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.16.2-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Op mentions

> my problem is fixed. Internet speed was very slow so issue occurs.

But do also consider that GitHub disabled just yesterday (Feb. 22 2018) deprecated algorithms:

> - TLSv1/TLSv1.1: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web, API, and git connections to https://github.com and https://api.github.com.
> - diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com
> - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com

Upgrading to the latest Git should be enough to not be no

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same error in a Linux environment. Turned out environment variable (i.e. `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`) on my VM were set incorrectly.

You would want to check:

- if you are behind a firewall
- if you need to use a proxy to access internet/github. If so, make sure to set `https_proxy` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is your repository's server issue (of SSL certificate). Better contact repository administrator. By the way `try accessing ssh URL` of the same repository (if you have access).

Comment: I've also gotten this error when the server was serving git content over `http`, not `https`.

Answer (score 1):

If on Windows 10, updating to `git version 2.29.1.windows.1` ([link](https://git-scm.com/download/win)) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

My `https_proxy` variable was set to something like

```
https://X.X.X.X:XXXX
```

Changing to

```
X.X.X.X:XXXX
```

solved my problem.