# How can I update or check the version of my SSL library?

Tags: git, ssl

I have a problem with git,  I can not clone a remote repository onto my desktop. Here is the error:

```
Marian@Marian-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/codeProjects/kaneConcrete
$ git clone https://github.com/spabsa/Kane-Concrete-Construction.git 2
Cloning into ‘Kane-Concrete-Construction’…
remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD :wrong version number, errno 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

I tried many different suggested things:

- I was told to update my git version which I did and nothing happened.
- Then I updated the buffer size, that didn't work.
- I also cloned the same repo on my laptop, so it's not a network issue.
- Then I was told to try cloning another repository, that didn't work.
- I also tried disabling the real-time scanning on my ant-virus, that didn't work.
- Then I was told to update my SSL library. I don't even know what this is or how to do that despite me searching about this subject for a min.

Comment: Can you try the solution proposed in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/49728862/1345973 ? The size of the repository maybe huge and you need to configure the http post buffer size to retrieve it.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to ssl since git started enumerating objects and working on the cloning.

Comment: Should I use that exact command? is there anything personally unique about the number "524288000"?

Comment: No I don't think so. I guess it is the buffer size in bytes. Yes try use the sale command or change it slightly

Comment: Are you able to clone other repositories on github, or does it fail for all? Did you try cloning other repositories from other hosts? How did you install `git` and which version is it? On which OS are you and which version? If Unix like, you want to do `openssl version` to find details about your (most probable) "SSL" library. Also, more generally, when you say you did X or Y, you should detail what you did exactly

Comment: what's your git client version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920416/getting-fatal-error-at-the-time-of-git-pull-ssl-routinesssl3-get-record

Comment: I have git version 2.21.0.windows.1 which i downloaded from https://git-scm.com/downloads. I'm using windows 7 Home premium. I also tried cloning another repository. Same error?

Comment: This error means that something produced an invalid SSL record, which probably means that something is tampering with the connection. If you have antivirus, does disabling it help? Also, are you using a proxy of some sort?

Comment: I do have mcafee and I turned off real-time scanning. That didn't help. I don't know what a proxy is or how to check?

Comment: A proxy is a server or service that sits in the middle of your connection. It can provide filtering or caching functionality. They're usually found in corporate environments. If you have the `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variables set or one of the `http.proxy` Git config options, then you're using a proxy. If you don't know, you probably aren't.

Comment: Oh, ok. So what's my next move? I really need to clone these files so I can start working on them.

Comment: github provides https links for all repositories, so you can download the repository that way. It may work better.

Comment: I'm not technical at all, how would I download it? Through the zip files? Even still I would really like to get to the bottom of this